# Facebook FQL-Query returns empty result

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-fql

I'm trying to execute the following query on the FB-FQL:

```
SELECT id, tagged_uids, type, coords FROM location_post WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, '37.785834', '-122.406417') < 1000
```

Apart from the fact that the distance-parameter seems to return pretty arbitrary results, this query only works in the Graph-explorer. When I submit it from my app (iOS), all I get is an empty array.

My suspicion is that I'm missing some permissions - but I can't figure out which (and requesting all perms from a user seems a little too much :)

The permissons I request are:

```
@"user_photos",
@"user_videos",
@"read_stream",
@"status_update",
@"publish_stream",
@"publish_checkins",
@"user_checkins",
@"friends_checkins",
@"friends_photos",
@"email",
@"user_location",
@"friends_location"
```

Any ideas?

[EDIT SOLVED]

Sometimes it helps to read the docs :)

The missing permissions were «user_status» & «friends_status»

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the edit, the missing permissions were «user_status» & «friends_status»